# Criação de Lista Dinâmica Encadeada

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

estou estudando estrutura de dados pelo site: [Linguagem C Descomplicada - Estrutura de Dados](https://programacaodescomplicada.wordpress.com/indice/estrutura-de-dados/) e na aula 12 (3:52 min) o professor desenvolve a função que cria a lista:

```
// Implementação das funções
lista* criarLista(){
    lista* lde = (lista*) malloc(sizeof(lista));

    if(lde != NULL)
        *lde = NULL; // inicializa o ponteiro lde com NULL (conteúdo).

    return lde;
}
```

O fato é que eu não entendi a atribuição feita em `*lde = NULL`, já que o professor comenta que `*lde` é o ponteiro para a cabeça da lista e essa cabeça aponta para o próximo nó que é NULL. Logo, eu esperava algo como `*lde->prox = NULL`.
O professor trabalha com a modularização dos TADs, logo e divide o código entre o parte pública - cabeçalho (lde.h):

```
// Definição do tipo de dado a ser armazenado na lista
struct Aluno{
    float n1,
          n2,
          n3,
          n4;
    int matricula;
    char nome[50];
};

// Definição do ponteiro do tipo lista
typedef struct Elemento* lista;

/*Protótipos*/
// Funções básicas
lista* criarLista();
```

e a parte privada - implementação (lde.c):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio2.h>
#include "LDE.h"

// Definição do tipo de dado "lista"
struct Elemento{
    struct Aluno aluno;
    struct Elemento *proximo; // Apontador para a próxima estrutura do tipo struct (porque os elementos são estruturas)
};

// Apelidando a lista para facilitar a manipulação
typedef struct Elemento elmt;


// Implementação das funções
lista* criarLista(){
    lista* lde = (lista*) malloc(sizeof(lista));

    if(lde != NULL)
        *lde = NULL; // inicializa o ponteiro lde com NULL (conteúdo).

    return lde;
}
```

e o programa cliente/aplicação (teste.c):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio2.h>
#include "LDE.h"

struct Aluno estudante;

int main(){
    int opcao;
    lista* lst = NULL; 
    lst = criarLista();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A questão aqui refere o clássico `typedef` de ponteiro que pretende ajudar mas muitas vezes acaba por iludir visualmente:

```
typedef struct Elemento* lista;
```

Então pode não ser muito evidente mas `lista` é um ponteiro para um `struct Elemento`. Logo quando faz:

```
lista* lde = (lista*) malloc(sizeof(lista));
```

Está a criar um ponteiro para um elemento do tipo `lista`, ou seja um duplo ponteiro de `struct Elemento`. Por isso seria equivalente a ter feito:

```
struct Elemento** lde = (struct Elemento**) malloc(sizeof(struct Elemento*));
```

Cada nó é alocado e guarda-se o ponteiro para ele, e quando quer ter algo que aponta para um nó tem então um ponteiro de ponteiro. No caso ao fazer:

```
if(lde != NULL) //se conseguiu alocar memoria
    *lde = NULL; //coloque o ponteiro de nós a apontar para NULL
```

Está a dizer: se conseguiu alocar memória, coloque o ponteiro de nós a apontar para nada, representado por `NULL`.

Vamos representar visualmente as três alternativas face ao `lde`:

- `lde = NULL`:

  ```
    lde
  _______
  | NULL |
  --------
  ```

  `lde` "não aponta para nenhum endereço", ou aponta para o endereço nulo
- `*lde = NULL`:

  ```
    lde
  _______
  |_____|  ----> NULL
  ```

  `lde` aponta para um endereço valido mas nesse endereço tem `NULL`.
- `lde = (lista*) malloc(sizeof(lista))`

  ```
    lde           elemento*
  _______        _________       _________
  |_____|  ----> |_______| ----> | Aluno | 
                                 ---------
                                 | prox  | -------> NULL
                                 ---------
  ```

  Agora `lde` aponta para um nó alocado e válido. É evidente que tem 
  ponteiro de ponteiro, uma vez que tem duas setas. O `elemento*` corresponde ao ponteiro de um nó, que no diagrama anterior ficou a `NULL`.